# Draft-js saving and displaying HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm wondering if anyone came up with any tutorial / walk through for Draft-js to simply save editor state and display it as html to the user. I've been searching and trying and still unable to display html. It seems like most are just saving the editor state and reloading it into the editor instead of displaying it as html.

It seems like most go with convertFromRaw and convertToRaw, but the amount of steps included in that seems like there are quite a few steps that should be simplified, and the example here: https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-data-conversion.html#content seems like it's only used to place the content back in the editor later.

Maybe I'm not even looking at the right tool - I simply want an editor to save formatted text and display it. I'm not sure why the resources are so hard to find, or if I'm just looking in the wrong spots (seems like there are too many packages for Draft-js with not much documentation and examples IMO). However, I'm sure this must not be hard to accomplish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Draftjs is concentrating on displaying rich text within an editor. However, if you want to display the corresponding HTML you have to use an external package called draftjs-export-html.
`import {stateToHTML} from 'draft-js-export-html';`

you can get the html using `let html = stateToHTML(editorState.getCurrentContent(), options);` this will do the basic formatting of styles like bold, italic etc. You can also pass your own styling preferences of your draftjs entites using the option parameter.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/draft-js-export-html

Comment: Thanks for the resource, I've tried it out but when I render `html` like you've shown wrapped in curly braces `return({html})`, it just displays it in plaintext on the page. Is there some obvious step I'm missing?

Comment: You cannot print html through jsx. {html} wont work. You have to use `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={__html: html} />;`

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Comment: Ah perfect, works great! Thanks for the resources!